# What player do you use?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-player

After my experience with `FFmpeg` created content: different player, different results.

So what player do you use to look at you footage?

Does someone know a player where you can check current frame meta information (PTS, frame number, pict type)?

manu

Answer (score 2):

I was a rusted on MPC (and more recently its derivatives MPC-HC and MPC-BE) fan until recently when the MPC devs flagged that it would not be continued. So I started looking to see what else was out there.

While the MPCs are still very capable players I've increasingly been using [MPV](https://mpv.io/), another mplayer-derived open-source project.

- It has a fairly minimal UI (which IMHO is a good thing),
- it is GPU-rendered and seems to be pretty resource light–on my machine we've been watching 6K camera footage in ProRes without problems.
- It's easily configureable, has useful features such as colour management and HDR,
- plays most codecs and formats that I throw at it without problems
- It's cross platform, so if you swap between PC, OSX and Linux you can use it on all of them.

[image]

Another player that is useful to know is [djv-view](http://djv.sourceforge.net/). This comes with some very useful tools such as histograms, RAM-caching for smooth playback and jog-shuttling and so on. It doesn't have audio so it's nto a general purpose media player, but it's a real winner for playing image sequences that would struggle to play smoothly otherwise–as long as you have the RAM for it. This is also cross-platform, available for PC, OSX and a linux package manager near you.

[image]

Comment: i am looking for features like showing PTS, DTS, Frametype, Framenumber, Jumping from I-Frame to I-Frame

is this possible with one of those?

Comment: Not sure. They're both free, have a try and see.

Answer (score 1):

Different media players give different results not because of encoding software, but because of their own implementation of decoding functions or selection of the installed codecs.

IMHO the best players for serious work are `MPC` (`MPC-HC`) and `VLC`.